# Re-apply laravel where statement in a for each loop

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-collection

How do i re-apply a `where()` statement on a certain collection while being in a for each loop.

Im currently looping my parameters and i want to for each them all in a `where()` statement so i can filter a collection with these `where()` statements

---

my foreach here below: it currently is taking all `where()` results and merges them together, but i want all `where()` statements to apply to 1 single collection so it filters them out.

```
        $guides = new Collection;
        foreach($request->query() as $key => $value){
            if($guides->isEmpty()){
                $guides = SupportGuideTranslation::where($key, $value)->get();
            }
            else{
                $guides = $guides->toBase()->merge(SupportGuideTranslation::where($key, $value)->get());
            }
        }
        $guides = $guides->unique();
```

---

These are my parameters:

```
?active=2&language_id=2
```

---

This is the result of `$request->query()`:

```
^ array:2 [▼
  "active" => "2"
  "language_id" => "2"
]
```

---

My result now is that i get 6 records back (instead 2).

- 3 records with language_id=2 and active=1 (Wrong)
- 1 record with language_id=1 and active=2 (wrong)
- 2 record with language_id=2 and active=2 (Correct)

What i want is that it only shows the 2 records that follow both parameter rules instead having 2 separate collections merged.

Comment: you can pass array to where method: `where($request->query())`

Comment: @ChinhNguyen No, that's not possible. It returns an empty array.

Comment: you need to get SupportGuideTranslation with `active=2 and language_id=2` right?

Comment: @ChinhNguyen Yes.

Comment: do it in 1 query instead of loop: `SupportGuideTranslation::where($request->query())->get()`

Comment: Do you have an example of the actual vs the expected result?

Comment: @ChinhNguyen I have done that. It returns empty array: items[ ]

Comment: can you show me result of: `SupportGuideTranslation::where($request->query())->toSql();`

Comment: @ChinhNguyen "select * from `support_guide_translations` where (`active` = ? and `language_id` = ?)"

Comment: @ChinhNguyen by the way. It has to be done in a loop because i will have to filter out other parameters out of the query that aren't supposed to be in the where statement.

Comment: it looks like the query is fine, how about `SupportGuideTranslation::where($request->query())->dd();`

Comment: @ChinhNguyen ^ "select * from `support_guide_translations` where (`active` = ? and `language_id` = ?)"

^ array:2 [▼
  0 => "2"
  1 => "2"
]

Comment: That's definetely not the query. There have do be two queries according to your loop: `select * from support_guide_translations where active = ?` and `select * from support_guide_translations where language_id = ?`

Comment: @shaedrich i don't know what u mean, sorry.

Comment: You make multiple queries. One per iteration. So the query you posted can be the result of your code. It's simply impossible.

Comment: `select * from support_guide_translations where (active = 2 and language_id = 2)` run this query in you database directly (using console or phpMyAdmin) and see if it return correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add to the `QueryBuilder` without executing the query, what you are doing is executing one query each iteration. So instead build up the correct query, then execute it.

```
$query = SupportGuideTranslation::query();

foreach ($request->query() as $key => $value) {
    $query->where($key, $value);
}

$translations = $query->get();
```

Comment: this returns empty array :(

Comment: Then your query is wrong? dd($query->toSql()); and see what is executed

Comment: ^ "select * from `support_guide_translations` where `active` = ? and `language_id` = ?"

Comment: and assuming your input is correct as stated, that should return all where active = 2 and language_id = 2

Comment: if toSql() is that, it should 100% work, either you are connecting to the wrong database or your data is wrong.